# Ubuntu 16.04 Ivacy VPN Config

Tags: boot, command-line

Has anyone got [Ivacy](https://www.ivacy.com/) vpn going with openvpn in ubuntu, are there are extra things you have to change in the configuration?  I have openvpn setup properly because I've used it successfully before with another vpn.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using it on Ubuntu and this might help you: https://support.ivacy.com/setup_guide/how-to-setup-ivacy-pptp-protocol-manually-on-ubuntu/

If it doesn't than you can contact their Live Chat and discuss this with them, they'll surely help you in setting it up on Ubuntu too.